# Detect if private browser session is on Firefox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, firefox, private

I'm working on Rails app and I need to detect if I'm on Firefox private session using Javascript code or some JS plugin.
I'm testing on Firefox 43.

I was trying using Components.classes but this is undefined. The problem is like Firefox on private session uses Tracking protected, this is not loading some JS files and I need to know if I'm on private session (then Protected Tracking is enabled), and then, I'm not going to load this tracking JS files.

Thanks in advance.

I saw some posts to check if we are in private session on Chrome and Safari and these work well on these browsers but don't work on Firefox!

Comment: I think you might have an easier time detecting tracking protection or some other symptom of private browsing than detecting private browsing itself directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no truly reliable way to detect private browsing.  That said, I've used [this](https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956) in the past, and it worked quite well for me!